# NodeJS localhost refuse to connect

Tags: node.js

I tried to write a simple code in NodeJS to test if I could connect to the localhost or not. However, when I ran `node server.js` then went to the browser to type `localhost:5000`, the localhost refused to connect (I installed the NodeJS).

server.js

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
    if (req.url == '/') { 
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });   
    res.write('<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>');
    res.end();

}
else
    res.end('Invalid Request!');

});

server.listen(5000);

console.log('Node.js web server at port 5000 is running..')
```

Comment: Your code should work, how do you run the node server? `node server.js`?

Comment: Do the logs print out that last line there **before** you open the browser? Or do you get some error?

Comment: I used node server.js to execute the code and the logs print out the line "Node.js web server at port 5000 is running.." before I opened the browser

Comment: And does your browser get a 500 back from an OPTIONS call??

Comment: No, it only displays this site can't be reached. Localhost refused to connect

Comment: I solved this as I ran the code in Ubuntu VirtualBox but I tried to open localhost on macOS browser, I should open the browser inside the Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I solved this as I ran the code in Ubuntu VirtualBox, but I tried to open localhost on a macOS browser. I should have opened the browser inside of Ubuntu.